# Highlighting 3rd row of a table in an email generated by SQL+HTML script

Tags: html, css

I am using SQL+HTML script to send an email containing columns of a table `mytable`. The table has only 3 rows. The third row is the difference of first 2 row and hence I want to highlight it (with some background color). I came across `nth-child()` selector but I am not sure how it should be used here.

```
N'<table id="box-table" >' +
N'<tr><th>Order Date</th>
<th>System</th>
<th>SKU Count</th>
<th>OUTL $</th>
<th>OH $</th>
</tr>' +
CAST ( ( 
SELECT td = Order_date,'',
td = System,'',
td = SKU_Count,'',
td = OUTL_$,'',
td = OH_$
FROM mytable
FOR XML PATH('tr'), TYPE 
) AS NVARCHAR(MAX) ) +
N'</table><br/>'+
```

Comment: What do you mean with "this case" ? Is it different than other cases?

Comment: Don't use `nth-child` or `nth-of-type`, as emails have horribly bad CSS support.  If you wish for it to work in email clients, either add an inline-style to the 3rd `<tr>`, or give it a class, and change the classes background.

Comment: I don't have 3 `<tr>`

Answer (score 0):

you could use ROW_NUMBER()

```
N'<style type="text/css">
    .row3 {
        background-color: red;
    }
</style>'+ ...
SELECT 'row' + CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [Order_date]) AS VARCHAR(3)) AS [@class],  
    td = Order_date,'',
    td = System,'',
    td = SKU_Count,'',
    td = OUTL_$,'',
    td = OH_$
FROM mytable
FOR XML PATH('tr'), TYPE ...
```

Comment: the `[@class]` allows you to set the class of the `tr` in this select statement. If you include the style snippet within the email it will allow you to set the background for the 3rd row based on the class name of `.row3`.